# Functions in Tensorflow

Tags: function, tensorflow, neural-network

(Original question edited)
In Tensorflow we often need to define functions, which contain variables, to implement on intermediate nerual network layers.  Is there a way of evaluating the output of this e.g.:

```
import tensorflow as tf
def Mult(mult):
    A = tf.get_variable([2,2], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
    B = tf.get_variable([2,2], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
    return mult*tf.matmul(A,B)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    # Here we alter the variables A,B in some fashion e.g. in an optimisation algorithm
    print(Mult(A,B))
```

Produces an error

Answer (score 1):

There are three bugs in your code:

1. if you create a function that takes A,B as parameters it does not make much sense to create variables in the function with the same name. So either remove the `A` and `B` arguments or don't create the variables inside the function.
2. `Mult(A,B)` returns a tensor. To retrieve the value of that tensor you need to evaluate it in a session. A session keeps track of the values of the parameters `A` and `B` from which it can calculate the value for `Mult(A,B)`.
3. the `tf.get_variable` function requires a `name` argument.

The code below fixes your errors:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def Mult():
    A = tf.get_variable('A', shape=[2,2], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
    B = tf.get_variable('B', shape=[2,2], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
    return tf.matmul(A,B)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = Mult()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(result))
```

Comment: Why does it produce an error if the lines:  result = ......    ,     and sess.run(tf .....     are switched?

Comment: `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` initializes all global variables in the graph. If you call it before calling `Mult()` there are no variables yet in the graph and you end up with two unitialized variables (`A` and `B`).

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the code. First of all, since you pass the variables `A` and `B` to the function, you don't need to initialize them inside the function. So the function should look like:

```
def Mult(A,B):
    return tf.matmul(A,B)
```

Next, you need to define the variables before you initialize them, so the row

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

should appear after you defined the variables.

In addition, if you want to get the numerical value of `Mult(A,B)`, you should print

```
sess.run(Mult(A,B))
```

and not just `Mult(A,B)` (because the latter will only give you a tensor object).

Finally, you need to provide a name to the variables you defined. `[2,2]` is the shape (the second argument to the function). The first argument should be the name.

Here is the corrected code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
def Mult(A,B):
    return tf.matmul(A,B)

A = tf.get_variable('A',shape=[2,2], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
B = tf.get_variable('B',shape=[2,2], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(Mult(A,B)))
```

This prints

```
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
```